# MPMoviePlayerViewController in Landscape when dismissed Portrait

Tags: uitableview, ios7, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have got a TableViewController which is only for PortraitMode. Now I want to play a video when a cell is touched. 
In my App Delegate I am working with the method:

```
- (NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window {

if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
    NSLog(@"ja1");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
} else {
    if ([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        NSLog(@"ja2");

        // look for it inside UINavigationController
        UINavigationController *nc = (UINavigationController *)[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController];

        // is at the top?
        if ([nc.topViewController isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
            NSLog(@"ja3");
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;

            // or it's presented from the top?
        } else if ([[nc.topViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]) {
            NSLog(@"ja4");
            return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
        }
    }
}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

to make it possible to turn to landscape while watching the video.

I show an instance of MPMoviePlayerViewController from my TableView

```
- (void)playVideo {
NSURL *movieURL = [NSURL URLWithString:MYURL];
MPMoviePlayerViewController *c = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:movieURL];

// Remove the movie player view controller from the "playback did finish" notification observers
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:c
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:c.moviePlayer];

// Register this class as an observer instead
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(movieFinishedCallback:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:c.moviePlayer];

// Set the modal transition style of your choice
c.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;

// Present the movie player view controller
[self presentViewController:c animated:YES completion:^{}];

// Start playback
[c.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[c.moviePlayer play];
}
```

Now I have the problem, that when I dismiss the MPMoviePlayerViewController in landscape mode I want to rotate it back to Portrait mode. But my MasterViewController (=TableView) is still in landscape mode.

Can you help me out!

Answer (score 0):

Implement following orientation methods in your MasterViewController. which will make your MasterViewController to stay portrait.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return false;
}
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
// Returns interface orientation masks.
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{  
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```